# How reliable is the d20 PFSRD?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I'm beginning Pathfinder and I'm curious as to how reliable the information is on that site.

I only ask because occasionally I find it is lacking sources and I know it also has some 3rd party items on the site as well and I don't know if any of that ever seeps into the mechanics.

thank you!

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate. It's about d20PFSRD, but it asks a different, more specific question about it. My answer is that while it's technically very reliable, the organization is totally different, and it may be harder to distinguish between different sources. Suppose your group plays with only Core+APG, Paizo.com makes it very clear what you can use, whereas of d20PFSRD, you need to filter out a lot of other sources. And even if you use everything, d20PFSRD also has 3rd party/fan material. Clearly labeled, but still, be careful.

Comment: Yeah, as someone who wrote an answer to the other question, I can't agree that they're duplicate.   I would have written a very different type of answer to this particular question.